# Debug navigator memory in Xcode grows

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have developed an application for iPhone, and now to check any memory leak.

I switch two `ViewControllers` (two screens), vc1 and vc2 as follow:

1. Click a button in vc1 to start vc2, by using [`self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil]`;
2. Click a button in vc2 to close vc2 and go back to vc1, by using [`self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil`];

I repeats the step 1 and 2 for ten times.

In *Xcode*, Debug Navigate memory, the memory grows each time

screen at vc1, memory: 6MB

screen at vc2, memory: 6.6MB

screen at vc1, memory: 6.3MB

screen at vc2, memory: 6.8MB

screen at vc1, memory: 6.5MB

screen at vc2, memory: 7MB

screen at vc1, memory: 6.6MB

screen at vc2, memory: 7MB

screen at vc1, memory: 6.6MB

screen at vc2, memory: 7.2MB

...

screen at vc1, memory: 7MB

vc1 starts with memory 6MB, but at the end, it uses 7MB, after 10 time switching of vc1 and vc2.

I verify my code and also run Xcode Instrument to find memory leak, but the instrument shows no leak.

What cause the memory to grow from 6MB to 7MB?

My application has memory leak?

Or it is the normal behaviour of iOS?

Comment: I used dealloc, and dealloc of vc2 is called and shown with NSLog.

Comment: Sounds good. Now measure again using Instruments on a device.

Comment: Instruments shows no leak. But memory keeps growing each time switch view controllers. You may try in your developed application, I guess same result may happen.